# How can add span to parent menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I add span that have arrow picture for the ul.menu li that have child elements (ul.sub-menu li ).

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">hhh</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hhh</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">kkk</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">kkk</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">kkk</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">hhh</a></li>
</ul>
```

how can do that by jquery or css

Comment: I don't see any JS code, add the code that you tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

This jQuery code should work:

```
$(".submenu").parent().append("<span class='arrow'></span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper way exist to give you perfect answer, because you don't provide complete code (JS, HTML).

But as your requirement: if you want to add a span to parent menu -

First you need to select parent element, for this you can use `.parent()` jquery selector.

**Jquery selector .parent() : -**  Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[Here complete documentation of jquery .Parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

And second:

use `.append()` - for adding element to the end of selected element

```
$(".submenu").parent().append("<span class='arrow'></span>");
```

use `.prepend()` - for adding element to the beginning of selected element

```
$(".submenu").parent().prepend("<span class='arrow'></span>");
```

Comment: +1, nice expansion of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("ul.submenu").closest('li').children('a').append("<span> ▼</span>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/psAsW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want add class to ul tag along with menu

```
$(".submenu").parent().parent().append("<span class='arrow'></span>");
```